# Why does not the electrons in a conducting the wire end?

Tags: electricity

> What happens to the electrons in a conducting wire, Why does not the electrons in the wire end?

I have read answers on the web but have not manage to understand, the free electrons from the conducting wire actually move to the electric device? if so after a while those free electrons will finish?

Comment: Welcome to Physics Stack Exchange. Please read our [FAQ on question titles](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6413/how-do-we-write-good-question-titles) to learn how to write helpful, meaningful titles for your questions.

Answer (score 2):

The free electrons are only the reason why electricity can flow at all. Really the "source of electrons is the battery and it stops providing electrons when the electric potential in the cell is depleted.
The number of electrons in a circuit does not change but their distribution changes. To create potential, electrons are moved to make one side of the battery more negatively charged than the other. When the wire is connected the electrons can flow back to the more positive side.